# reference applet class in Maven webapp archetype eclipse classnotfound exception

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, applet

I am trying to run an applet in HTML 5 file or JSP page in a java web dynamic project created with maven webapp archetype and imported into Eclipse.

folder structure:

Myproject
  - Deployment Descriptor: myproject
  - JAX-WS Web Service
  - Java Rsources 
       -src/main/java
           com.mypackage.servlets
            servletsrc.java

```
   -Applets
       com.myappletpackage.applets
        appletcode.java

   Libraries
 Java Script Resources
 Deployed Resources

src/
     /main/ 
      java/ ... sourcecode
     /webapp
         /HtmlfileCallingApplet.html
         /file.html
target/
    /myproject
             /META-INF
             /WEB-INF/
                     /Classes/
                           /com/
                           /mypackage
                                 servlet.class
                            /myappletpackage
                                 appletcode.class
                /lib/
```

what is the magical code to refernce appletcode.class in my html page ? if i deploy this 
package , here is what i tried

```
var attributes =                  {codebase:'http://localhost/Myproject/WEBINF/classes/com/MyAppletPackage/Appletcode.class',
                  code: 'com.MyAppletPackage.Appletcode.class',
                  archive: 'MyProject.war',
                  width: '800', 
                  height: '600'};
var parameters = {java_arguments: '-Xmx256m'}; // customize per your needs
var version = '1.5'; // JDK version
deployJava.runApplet(attributes, parameters, version);


            `
```

Answer (score 0):

In a JSP page, i copied the class file to the path right next to the JSP page 
and used this in the page :

`<jsp:plugin type="applet" code="Appletcode.class" codebase="." width="400" height="400"> 
<jsp:fallback> <p>Unable to load applet</p>
</jsp:fallback>
</jsp:plugin>`

Now i am having problems referencing JAR files in the plugin , where should these files be?